# Ruby on Rails Rails models with 'circular' reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I'm trying to create a base model 'Client':

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Clients has a list of Audits:

```
class CreateAudits < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :audits do |t|
      t.references :client, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Each client has a list of audits.  That part is easy.  Where I'm a bit unsure of is how to handle adding a Client to each audit.  Here's what I mean...  A client has a name and each year or so we want to allow an Audit to happen where the client can review each of their fields and change it, go through an approval process, and then ultimately end up changing the client attributes.

I want an Audit to 'have_a' Client so I can track the audit changes to the client before pushing them back into the base Client and closing out the audit.

It should look something like this:

```
Client
  name
  has_many Audits
```

```
Audit
  status
  belongs_to Client
  has_a Client # named tempClient or something --> How do I create this relation?
```

I keep getting the error :

```
➜  project_rails git:(main) ✗ rake db:migrate                                      
== 20221028145314 AddClientToAudits: migrating ================================
-- add_reference(:audits, :client, {:null=>false, :foreign_key=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

you can't define an already defined column 'client_id'.
```

**How can I create a child client of the audit?**

-- edit --

To expound:

One solution is to just keep the same attributes in the audit that is in the client.  But then one would have to remember when they, say, add an address to the client to then go and add an address to the audit as well with the exact same names.  This is why I'm trying to reuse the client object -- any attributes added to the client automatically gets added to the audit.

Open to other ideas for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you correctly, you already have the correct relationships set up in your database.  Take a look at your `structure.sql` or `schema.rb` file to confirm that these relationships are already correct.  Another way to confirm is to use the `rails console` to create a junk client, a junk audit, and relate them.  Then try `audit.client_id` to confirm that already exists.

I think what you need to do is add the following to the Rails model file so that you can reference the client from the audit in code.

Like:

```
class Audit < ApplicationRecord
  # other attributes

  belongs_to :client, required: true

  # ...
end
```

Now you can say `audit.client` to do your updates.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!

To be clear, I'm looking for the Audit to not only 'belong_to' a Client, but also 'has_a' "Temporary" Client where I can store the audit values while the audit goes through an approval process.  At the end of the process the "tempClient" will be pushed into the "client".

I hope that makes sense?  I updated the Audit model above to show a bit more accurately.